# SQL Developer for importing from Excel

Tags: oracle, excel, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have installed SQL Developer in my system, but how can i utilize the GUI.
I am new to this and i want to import datas from Excel to Oracle database using SQL Developer

Thanks in advance

Comment: I recently addressed this question for another saeeker.  They were using DbSaint rather than SQL Developer but the answer remains the same.  Check out my response  here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404098/dbsaint-retrieve-form-excel/3404574#3404574

Answer (score 13):

At what point did you get stuck?

A fast track:

1. Create a connection to the database in SQL Developer
2. Create a table as a destination for the xls data
3. save excel data as csv
4. right click on the table from step 2
5. select 'import data'
6. select csv file
7. use the wizzard

and bob is your uncle

Folowing methed creates the table for you

1. Create a connection to the database in SQL Developer
2. right click on tables folder
3. Choose Import data
4. select xls
5. use the wizzard (provide table name, row limit, select columns, datatype per column)
6. Finish

Answer (score 5):

A recent version<sup>*</sup> of [SQL*Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) is able to read Excel workbooks.

[Jeff Smith](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/) has written very detailed tutorial [How to Import from Excel to Oracle with SQL Developer](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/04/how-to-import-from-excel-to-oracle-with-sql-developer/).

<sup>*</sup> *a version 3.2 at the moment of writing*